# Too many re-render problems with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, query-string

I have some cards in my application that can lead to another pages through clicks. So I have a main component that contains a button like this:

```
function MainComponent(props) {
.
.
.
  const handleClick = (key) => {
    history.push("/exampleurl/" + key);
  };
```

Then according to the key passed, I have to make a request that gives me some information required to display it. As default I have my initial state as null, and when it completes the request, it changes to the object I got. But as soon as I click on the card, I get the re-render error.

```
function MyComponent(props) {

    let { key } = useParams();

    const [myObject, setMyObject] = React.useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('/myendpoint/' + key).then( response => {
            let myObject = response.data
            setMyObject(myObject)
        })
    }, [key])
```

I suppose that the solution is avoiding the key value to update when it changes the state. But i am not finding the solution to this trouble.

Edit: The route that leads to the components:

```
          <Route path="/inbox">
            <MainComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/exampleurl/:key">
            <NewComponent />
          </Route>
```

Comment: Can you add your `Router` code? Just for make sure about `key` naming in the first place

Comment: Can you check if `let { key = null} = useParams();` follow up by `useEffect(() => { key && axios.....}` make any difference?

Comment: What is your definition of re-render error in this case? I mean, what is the expected behaviour and what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to the `handleClick` function.

Every time this method is called, you push a new entry to the history stack. Which analyze your defined routes and render the linked component. In your case, it is the same component, but I am not sure if the router is capable to determine it, therefore I would expect a re-render.

Maybe a solution would be to include another state which is responsible to inform the component of the current obj being displayed on the screen. So `key` will be responsible only for the route parameter and this new state will be responsible for the internal navigation.

```js
function MyComponent(props) {

    let { key } = useParams();

    const [myObject, setMyObject] = React.useState(null)
    const [displayedObj, setDisplayedObj] = React.useState('');

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('/myendpoint/' + key).then( response => {
            let myObject = response.data
            setMyObject(myObject)
            setDisplayedObj(key)
        })
    }, [key, displayedObj]) // we listen for displayedObj too
```

and then in the `handleClick` we update this new state. This will trigger the `useEffect` and therefore update the `myObject` state to the new value:

```js
const handleClick = (key) => {
    setDisplayedObj(key); 
    // This will trigger the useEffect and refresh
    // the data displayed without reloading the page
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but my handleClick function is mounted in another component. I will edit it to make clearer.